# Refresh each second with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am logging to refresh a page each sec, and displaying a `console.log` message:

```
function refreshEachMinute() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "minutesrefresh.php",
        //data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            //alert('ref');
            console.log('ok');
        }
    });
} // end function refresh

// refresh each minute
setInterval(refreshEachMinute, 1000);
```

The alert message shows, but the `console.log` does not. In addition, `minutesrefresh.php` is not loading in the Firebug bar.

Comment: Where are you testing this? What do you mean by “not loading” — any particular error?

Comment: `setInterval(refreshEachMinute, 1000)` will refresh each **second**, not each minute. Also, given the asynchronous and single threaded nature of javascript, you may be sending a request before the previous one has finished and getting responses in a different order to the requests.

Comment: Put the `console.log` before `alert`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue sometime back. So, instead of doing it like this, I changed it to:

```
function refreshEachMinute() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "minutesrefresh.php",
        //data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            setTimeout(refreshEachMinute, 1000);
            console.log('ok');
        }
    });
}

$(function(){setTimeout(refreshEachMinute, 1000)});
```

Comment: I just reorganize the code and now it works, I tested with 1 sec instead of waiting for a long minute, thanks for your help